# Split wp_get_archives across 2 columns

Tags: wordpress

I have searched for hours, and found things close, but not exactly what I need. I do a lot of HTML/CSS, but am not good at PHP. (I have a lot of respect for those who can do PHP!)

I need to display a list of the WordPress archive months for 2016 and 2015. They should flow evenly across two columns.

For example, in one column, you see Feb 2016, Jan 2016, (etc.) Sept 2015, August 2015. In the second column, you have July 2015, June 2015 (etc.) Jan 2015.

So there would be 7 months in each column at this time. Next month, there will be 8 in one column, 7 in the next, when March 2016 is added automatically.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I think I could write it for you, but that's not the point of this site.
Basically you will calculate the number of rows needed. Use integer division `(count+1)/2` will work whether you have an odd or even number of months. That is 11 or 12 will return 6. Code a for loop to repeat this number of times. Each row `i' holds  month[i] and month[i-maxRows]. Output the html for a tr and two td's each time around the loop. Make a special case of the last row if there is an odd number of months.

Comment: Thanks Bryan, I do see the general idea, I just can't make it happen. Plus, does your idea list the 7 recent months vertically, then begin a new column listing the rest? Or are consecutive months side by side in one row?

Comment: It would put 1 and 8 in the first row, 2 and 9, in the next, etc. and 7 and 14  in the last.
I can't edit my first comment, but it should have read `month[i+maxRows]` of course. (plus not minus)

Comment: I get it, thanks -- and thanks for the correction, makes sense now. Would people be more likely to help with the code if I got started -- even though I don't know what I'm doing -- then people could correct? I don't want to misuse this site at all -- I have found it so helpful in the past.

Comment: I'm relatively new here, but I think that's the case. I don't quite understand why some questions get voted down - maybe because they show no research or effort?